# Calling function from <form>

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I am aware that you are not able to use the onLoad attribute in a `<form>` like `<form id"form" onload="javascript:test()">`, you can only do this in a `<body>`

My question is, is there any attribute that you can put in the  to call a function when the form is loaded or is there a different way to do this?

EDIT:

So like this is it

```
<form jwcid="form">
<script>
function checkForChange() {
var approvalStatus = document.getElementById('licensingStatus').value;
if(approvalStatus == "Pass"){
    document.getElementById('licensingApprovalDate').setAttribute("validators", "validators:maxDateToday,required");
} else {
    document.getElementById('licensingApprovalDate').setAttribute("validators", "validators:maxDateToday");
}   
}
</script>
.....
```

Comment: You can put the code in a `script` tag after the `form`.

Comment: [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) are pointless when there is no loop. Don't stick `javascript:` there.

Comment: @FelixKling - sorry you might have miss understood the question, i want to call the function the when the page is loading

Comment: @Hip: Yes. When the page loads, the form is parsed first and then the following script tag. At the moment the code contained in the tag is executed and the form exists (it was just parsed). Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @FelixKling - sorry, i misunderstood your answer, you where right, it is working now :) thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms don't use external data to build them (the body can load images, iframes can load external documents, etc).

So:

```
</form>
<script> /* The form has loaded. Do your stuff */ </script>
```

Comment: this didnt work either, i can call the function, but what i want is the function to be called when the page is first loaded

Comment: So put `functionName()` where the comment says Do your stuff?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "form is loaded"? I think you mean "when the form is submited". The attribute is "onsubmit": `<form id="form" onsubmit="javascript:test()">`

Your funktion has to return either true or false whether the form shall be submitted or not.